# How to show only one name on each chart series

Tags: c#, charts, dynamic-chart-series

[image: Chart with different series]I am creating a chart with multiple series and i would like to show only one series name for each series like the example shown at the picture.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlxdb.png)

I have different series like series[4], series[5] with spline chartType and the name of the each series has been already set at the design stage ( like "RH50%" , "RH40%").

The problem is when i have set the property of the series name true, the name showns each points of the series.

I can not find the way to shwo series name, however see below code ;

```
chartPsy.Series[5].Label = "RH50%";
chartPsy.Series[5].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
```

and the result is shown within this picture ( all the points has shown with series name string instead of only one )
[image: Series name shown as repeated]

Comment: _I would like to show only one series name for each series_ Um, what do you mean? Only one series name in total (which) or the name of each series?? How do you show those names now? Can you show the code? Is it even a MSChart?

Comment: @TaW Thank you for the comment, i have updated the question with the samples

Comment: Ah. Well, what you see is one value per datapoint and that value is not really a dp.value but the string you set. You can decide to set only a Label for one DataPoint per Series. Replace both lines with maybe `chartPsy.Series[5].Points[100].Label = "RH50%";` Pick a suitable point index! - Of course you can do it in a loop over all series and use the Series.Name..

Comment: @TaW Great, it works! Thank you.